# Drawable shape with arrow in the middle of the shape border

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, shapes

[image]

How i can make a drawable file to have a view like this image?

Comment: use [NinePatchDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable)

Comment: do you have any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **solution** of the image with **drawabe**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color= "@color/themeColor"></solid>
                <size android:width="150dp" android:height="100dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="12%" android:pivotY="-140%" >
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```